# Preview image before submit.

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a HTML script like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <output id="show_img1"></output>
</div>
<div class="fileinput-button">
    <input type="file" id="files1" name="files[]"/>                     
</div>
<div class="gallery">
    <output id="show_img2"></output>
</div>
<div class="fileinput-button">
    <input type="file" id="files2" name="files[]"/>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
    <output id="show_img3"></output>
</div>
<div class="fileinput-button">
    <input type="file" id="files3" name="files[]"/>
</div>
```

I want preview images that have been selected in the tag `<output></output>` with id like above as identifier. 
I have tried this [script](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of image preview on `img` tag

```
<input type="file" id="files1" name="files[]"/>
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();            
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }            
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#files1").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/2cEXz/)

Comment: i tried for improve your answer...but it's still not work... :(


  [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2cEXz/1/)

Comment: Awesome...need an additional attributes. it's not occurred to me.

thanks alot for my big brother @suhail :D :)